# Как достать следующее AUTO_INCREMENT значение из таблицы?

Tags: mysql, java-ee, jdbc

В схеме `onlineshop` есть таблица `orders` с полем `id` которое `primarykey` и при этом само увеличивается на единицу, следующим запросом хочу достать следующее значение (т.е. мне необходимо узнать каким будет `id` у элемента когда я его добавлю в след. раз)

```java
public static final String FIND_CURRENT_AUTO_INCREMENT = "SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`"
        + "FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES "
        + "WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'onlineshop' "
        + "AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'orders'";
```

Так выглядит метод:

```java
@Override
public int findCurrentOrderId() throws DAOException {
        
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
        
    try (Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQLQueriesStorage.FIND_CURRENT_AUTO_INCREMENT)) {
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        resultSet.next();
        return resultSet.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException | ConnectionPoolException e) {
        logger.warn("Current id finding error", e);
        throw new DAOException("service.commonError", e);
    } finally {
        closeResultSet(resultSet);
    }
        
}
```

Но по какой то причине всегда возвращается цифра 4

Comment: а зачем вам знать, каким будет следующий id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно доставание только что полученного ID - шника из базы Вы можете сделать примерно так:

```sql
INSERT INTO [TestTable] (name) VALUES ($name); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);
```

При этом Вам вернется тот ID, с которым вставилась в таблицу текущая строка.

Но Вы пишете, что "мне необходимо узнать каким будет id у элемента когда я его добавлю в след. раз"

Строго говоря, мне кажется это невозможным. Ведь кроме Вас (или текущего потока, который работает с таблицей) вставки в неё может делать другой процесс.

Если Вы уверены, что такого не произойдёт - можете просто к полученному таким способом занчению прибавить единицу.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет мне, кое как, помог. Но я пришел к другому решению, я генерирую Id сам на сервис layer'e , я новичок в этом плане, поэтому могу допускать очень глупые ошибки

Comment: Ну, тут трудно дать совет, не зная задачу. Например, при импорте большого кол-ва строк в таблицу такое решение работает нормально, так как к таблице в момент импорта имеет доступ один процесс. Если же это web, то там одновременно несколько пользователей могут работать с таблицей. я бы немного опасался ситуации, когда двое одновременно сгененрируют на своей стороне одинаковый ID-шник